# Parse relative URLs in cross-origin AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I am writing a Chrome extension. I want to make an AJAX request to a remote URL, parse the return data as HTML and then interact with the DOM, like click links:

```
$.ajax({
    url: remote_url,
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).find('some element').click()
    }
})
```

The problem is that relative URLs (`/x/y/`) on the page referred to by `remote_url` are being parsed as part of the chrome extension's address space when creating a new DOM with `$(data)`, like `chrome-extension://abc/x/y/`.

I suspect that this is related to some cross-origin protection. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Can you not use the full URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve the relative links using HTML5 [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URL) class:

```
$data = $(data);
$data.find('[href]').each(function() {
    var href = this.getAttribute('href'); # 'this' is a DOM element
    if (href.indexOf('://') < 0) {
        this.href = new URL(href, remote_url);
    }
});
```

Or use HTML5 [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) with [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element to resolve all relative links, not just in `href`.

- `data` contains a fragment without html/body:

  ```
  var $doc = $(new DOMParser().parseFromString('<html><head><base href="' +
      remote_url + '"></head><body>' + data + '</body></html>', 'text/html'));
  ```
- `data` contains entire page:

  ```
  var $doc = $(new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, 'text/html'));
  $('head', $doc).append('<base href="' + remote_url + '">');
  ```

```
$doc.find('some element').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving that URL as a string I would just parse it up with some regular old Javascript and remove the parts you don't want. If you want some more help, just post the full string you're receiving and the string that you need and I can take a look. You'll probably just end up using a .split().pop().join() kind of a thing, but I'd love to take a look and give you a definitive answer.